# How to connect existing wall switch to a new remote controlled fan?

Tags: electrical

Just replaced an old fan with a new remote controlled fan but would still like to use the preexisting wall switch to either power the fan off or at least control the light.  Is it possible to do this?

I have white black and red coming from ceiling.  The remote has black, white, and blue wires to fan and black and white for power.

Help! & Thanks!

Comment: Does the existing fan remote support dimming the lights?  Are you bent on keeping the remote that came with the fan, or is changing out the wall-switch and/or fan-remote an option?  Also, can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box?

Comment: If you cut the power from the ordinary switch, you will not be able to use the remote control. You can still use the wall switch for on/off, but it will be for power to the complete unit.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to modify the switch wiring so that black is *always-hot* from the supply, and red is *switched-hot* coming off the switch.

Then, at the fan, you take the cable from the switch, and you connect black (always-hot) to the supply side of the fan controller.  The red (switched-hot) goes directly to the fan's **lamp**.

You would certainly want to have the light switch control the fan's light, because Code requires that there be a light switch in the room, and it must operate a light.

The black wire from the /3 from the switch goes to the fan control module.  The fan control module connects onward to the fan motor wire.  If the control module is capable of controlling the light, it'll have another wire for that (blue?)  Cap that wire off.